# Crash in localtime() but gmtime() works

Tags: c++, time, crash, exc-bad-access, localtime

I have an EXC_BAD_ACCESS in the function below:

```
time_t dateTime(getCurrentTimestamp());
tm *calculatedTime;
calculatedTime = localtime(&dateTime); 
tm *dateTimeCopy = new tm();
memcpy(dateTimeCopy, calculatedTime, sizeof(tm));
return dateTimeCopy;
```

The EXC_BAD_ACCESS happens in localtime(). Which I can not explain. If I change local time to gmtime it is working just fine. What could be the reason for this behaviour?

EDIT: Fixed an error in this code. As mentioned by Rufflewind. The crash still exists however.

EDIT 2: With localtime_r it is working as well. I will probably end up using it as shown below:

```
time_t dateTime(valueDateTime);
tm *dateTimeCopy = new tm();
localtime_r(&dateTime, dateTimeCopy);
```

Comment: On which operating system? Could be some [memory corruption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_corruption) elsewhere and before! Try using [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/)

Comment: The operating System is Mac OSX, I will take a look at valgrind

Comment: I just read unfortunately valgrind does not support mac OSX 10.9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in a comment above we moved completely away from using the `localtime` function. It accesses shared memory and seems to be not thread save or having other issues (at least in clang / ios / mac os).

We moved to use `localtime_r` or similar functions which seem to work without issues. Here is the code again which I also posted in the Question itself:

```
time_t dateTime(valueDateTime);
tm *dateTimeCopy = new tm();
localtime_r(&dateTime, dateTimeCopy);
```

Answer (score 3):

This line is suspicious:

```
memcpy(dateTimeCopy, &calculatedTime, sizeof(tm));
```

Note that

- `dateTimeCopy` has type `struct tm *`, whereas
- `&calculatedTime` has type `struct tm **`.

You probably meant:

```
memcpy(dateTimeCopy, calculatedTime, sizeof(tm));
```

Comment: Yeah that is an error thanks for spotting it. The program is crashing before that however.

Comment: Then it's probably an interaction with some earlier parts of the code, because I don't see why this code would fail when run in isolation.

Comment: I have yet to determine the reason for this. The variant posted in my edit works like charm. Maybe it was a threading issue or something since the normal localtime() is accessing some shared memory as far as I'm aware.